# module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I'm using Google Play Services `ads-lite` v.9.2.1.
When requesting Admob ads, the following is written to logcat:

```
W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(): Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
D/GmsModuleFndr(): Staging file APK's and updating chimera config...
D/GmsModuleFndr(): Staging file APKs completed
W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(): Failed to load module version after staging: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
W/DynamiteModule(): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0
E/AppStreamingHelper(): No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Test ads load and display fine.
Is that module `com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite` needed for live ads?

Answer (score -3):

It is against [`AdMob`](https://www.google.com/admob/) policy to click on your own live ads. During development and testing, use test ads. If you do need to render live ads before launch, avoid clicking on them. If you click on live ads, your AdMob account may be suspended. For more information, review the [AdMob policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860) and learn more about invalid activity.

Google treats invalid activity very seriously, analyzing all clicks and impressions to determine whether they fit a pattern of use that might artificially drive up an advertiser's costs or a publisher's earnings. If we determine that an AdMob account might pose a risk to our advertisers, we may disable that account to protect our advertisers' interests.

Publishers disabled for invalid activity or violating our policies may not be allowed any further participation in other Google publisher monetization solutions.